# GLOB to add_executable in cmakelists

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I was using gtest and cmake for my program and came across the following CMakeLists file in src dirctory

```
#Set BINARY to the project name IndexProject
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
 
# 1
# add_executable(ExampleProject main.cpp file1.cpp file1.h)
 
# 2
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})
add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})
add_library(${BINARY}_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

Since I saw using GLOB is not recommended I tried to change it to add_executable

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

# file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

add_executable(ExampleProject main.cpp func.cpp header.h)
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

 add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})

add_library(${BINARY}_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

If I run this i'm getting error as

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: ExampleProject_run
```

Comment: `set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})` seems odd to set a variable to the value of its contents. In c++ it would be like: `int x=1;` then later `x=x;`

Comment: You commented the GLOB line out: `# file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)` so the variable SOURCES is empty

Comment: so what should I do??

Comment: @rayne: You should pass non-empty source list to `add_executable`. If you want to fill that list with `GLOB`, then do that.

Comment: If you don't want to use GLOB you need to change this line `set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})
` to `set(SOURCES  EachSourceFileNameSeparatedByASpace)` for example `set(SOURCES main.cpp myfolder/mylib.cpp ...)`